# POST and GET are not working

Tags: php, android

I am practicing PHP and sending request on a server using REST Client add-on in Mozilla Firefox. I also tried different tool on chrome to check whether i am receiving data on server but unfortunately i am not receiving anything neither GET or POST. Only thing which i am able to receive is query string.

I didn't even write any code on server side just simple print commands.

```
<?php

var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);

echo "working";


?>
```

This is INPUT

```
> This is test message.
```

And this is output.

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
working
```

Like is said only thing that works is query string. And this server i am using is free web service don't know if this helps.

This is android code that i am trying to receive.

```
byte[] jsonBytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL("http://androidapplicati.base.pk/");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
             urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(jsonBytes.length);
             urlConnection
             .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    String.valueOf(jsonBytes.length));

             out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
             out.write(jsonBytes);
             out.flush();
             urlConnection.getInputStream().read();
```

Comment: Where is your [Form action] (http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) action ??

Comment: i am using addon in firefox that provide facility to send data in post or get.  http://restclient.net/

Comment: What do you mean with "This is INPUT". Input where?

Comment: Do you log them in a file? If you are just visiting the url, try something like domain.com/yourFile.php?test=working . `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` must show an array

Comment: The `REST API` datas should not be read like this

Comment: Its a addon in firefox if you just install it you will see.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8079048/1771402)

Comment: @blo query string work just fine.

Comment: can you say how your are posting datas from android to php ?

Comment: @Shah it means you are receiving all the data, the reason you are getting empty array is you can't do `POST` request via url. Make a cURL `POST` request and set return transfer to true.

Comment: @Shah now you had really messed up things. Can you tell what you want exactly. `Send data from Android and read it in PHP` or something else ?

Comment: Can you attach screen shot of RestClient with request & response .

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check did you pass any value using any method GET or POST. 
if yes
than This is not your coding problem . This is your hosting server issue. my advice never use any free servers because there is not technical support and they are not secure..

Your Code it working OK just change hosting server

Comment: Actually i tried it on local python server in ubuntu and it is working just fine but not on this server. But did you check it?

Comment: @blo Did you try anything. Any input.

Comment: @Shah sorry I don't know Android development, I can give a php code which will work, but can't help you on Android..

Comment: Sorry you are not asking first about android i checked it according to php and i don't know about android code. so sorry for that..

Comment: @blo yeah please share you php code so i might have an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `POST` example, you can test get by directly visiting or
`file_get_contents()`.

Post(cURL):

```
//domain and file to send request to
$url = 'http://yourdomain.com/file.php';

//parameters to send
$params = array(
          'field1' => 'value1',
          'field2' => 'value2'
        );

$data = http_build_query($params);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
//return the data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
//incase there is a redirect
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$return = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$output = json_decode($return, TRUE);

var_dump($output);
```

And on server side:

`echo json_encode($_REQUEST);`